# Empty Aggregate Query causes Access form to be blank

Tags: ms-access

I am building a question database.  Which has questions that are part of topics which are part of modules.  I would like to be able to filter questions based on topic or module.

Here is a MWE of my project

Question Table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    question_id    |  question_number  |     paper_id      |      year_id      |    is_selected    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 1 |                 1 |                 1 |                 1 |               Yes |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 2 |                 1 |                 1 |                 2 |               Yes |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 3 |                 2 |                 1 |                 1 |               Yes |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Topics Table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     topic_id      |   Topic Number    |    Topic Name     |     module_id     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 1 | 1.1               | Topic 1.1         |                 1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 2 | 1.2               | Topic 1.2         |                 1 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 3 | 2.1               | Topic 2.1         |                 2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 4 | 2.2               | Topic 2.1         |                 2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Join table between questions and topics

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| question_has_topi |     topic_id      |    question_id    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                 1 |                 1 |                 1 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                 2 |                 2 |                 1 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Modules Table

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|     module_id     |      number       |       title       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                 1 |                 1 | Module 1          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|                 2 |                 2 | Module 2          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I would like to be able to query at the module level and find questions WITHOUT duplicates at the module level because a question can be in two topics that are part of the SAME module.
The following query does just that-

AggregateQuery:

```
SELECT Question.question_id, First(Topics.topic_id) AS FirstOftopic_id, First(Module.module_id) AS FirstOfmodule_id
FROM ([Module] INNER JOIN Topics ON Module.module_id = Topics.module_id) INNER JOIN (Question INNER JOIN Question_has_topics ON Question.question_id = Question_has_topics.question_id) ON Topics.topic_id = Question_has_topics.topic_id
WHERE (((Module.module_id)=1))
GROUP BY Question.question_id
ORDER BY Question.question_id;
```

This displays questions belonging to Module 1 without repeats. However, if I now query for questions belonging to Module 2 I get a blank recordset as there are none assigned.  Given that my aggregate query is not updatable it does not contain any empty rows and my form is blank.

What I would like is if there are no records in the query then an empty record is assigned to the form's recordset.

The only way I can think to do this is:

```
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("AggregateQuery")
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Me.RecordSource = "UnaggregatedQuery"
       Else
        Me.RecordSource = "AggregateQuery"
    End If
```

where UnaggregatedQuery is:

```
SELECT Question.question_id, Topics.topic_id, Module.module_id
FROM ([Module] INNER JOIN Topics ON Module.module_id = Topics.module_id) INNER JOIN (Question INNER JOIN Question_has_topics ON Question.question_id = Question_has_topics.question_id) ON Topics.topic_id = Question_has_topics.topic_id
WHERE (((Module.module_id)=2));
```

This is updatable and therefore displays an empty record in my form.  While this works it feels very clunky.  Is there a way to assign an empty row rather than performing a second query?

I hope this is clear and makes sense

Thanks

Martyn

Comment: If you want to edit the result in the "empty case", there is no way around that - since aggregated queries are always read-only. If you just want to show an empty row, you could also perhaps do something with UNION, but that would probably be even more clunky.

Comment: AFAIK, UNION is not editable either.

Comment: I don't want to edit the record, but I get an empty record that means my form is not blank. If the aggregated query returns 0 records, it will be blank which is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I did a test and UNION can add the empty record. Try after the GROUP BY: `UNION SELECT Null, Null, Null FROM Module`. Another option might be to only allow user to select module that has related data. Why do your queries show static WHERE parameter?

Comment: Hi, thank you I will give it a try tomorrow. The queries were to provide a MWE to demonstrate my question.